# How do I move this JavaScript event from an inline event to its own .JS file?

Tags: javascript

Happened across a snip of JS that I've managed to make work for my uses, but as I'm brand new to javascript, I'm unsure whether I've understood how & why it works.  As it stands, it's inline (inside an html  tag, but I'd like to see it either in its own .js file so it can be used by several thousand links on one of several hundred pages on the site I'm putting together.

The purpose of the javascript I was looking for was to kill or disable a link (and only that link) on a page after it had been clicked once.  I didn't want it to disappear, as I'd seen mention of, just be made un-clickable.

Anyway, this is what I found.  Assistance is appreciated.

```
<A HREF="testvid.AVI" onclick="this.onclick=function(){return false;}"><DIV ID="BOX1">This is a video file</DIV></A>
```

Again, the question is, how to take that onclick event & place it in its own .js file.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With plain js you can use the same code:

document.getElementById('videoLink').onclick = function() {
    this.onclick = function() { return false; }
}

With jQuery you can try:

```
$("#videoLink").one('click', function() {
   $(this).click(function() {
        return false;
   });
});
```

**UPD:**

```
<A HREF="testvid.AVI" id="videoLink"><DIV ID="BOX1">This is a video file</DIV></A>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="filename.js"></script>
```

filename.js

```
$(function() {
    $("#videoLink").one('click', function() {
       $(this).click(function() {
            return false;
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: I assume you mean putting the above in a blank file & name it filename.js.  It'll reside in the same folder.

How do I change the above <a href> to reference it?

Comment: OK, did the following.  saved your original "plain js" code to filename.js.  
Added the line  
<script type="text/javascript" src="filename.js"></script> to the <head>.
Changed my original <a href> link to match yours.
That broke the function of the original script

Comment: added the info below the entry "filename.js" in your UPD to the filename.js file.
This also had no effect.

Comment: Have you added jquery script reference?

Comment: yep, both <script type=> lines are in the <head> section.  
the <a href> line matches yours above.  
And just for safety's sake, I put both the "document.getElementByID" line and the jQuery script in the filename.js file.

Comment: for reference, I put both files in a pastebin for you to look at.  They're at http://www.pastebin.org/420152